# What's the easiest way to put a pop up div at link / cursor location utilizing JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a need to create a small pop up information box when a user clicks on a certain link. Basically just a hidden div that floats above the content at the location almost like a tooltip, but requiring a click.

I've tried passing the event.clientX and clientY to the style.left and style.right properties, but it doesn't seem to put it at the correct location.

Just wondering if there's a very simple way that I'm overlooking.

Comment: I assume you mean `style.top`, not `right`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for this; it makes Javascript much simpler to write.

Your problem is that `event.clientX` (and `Y`) are relative the the element that the event came from.  You need to use `event.pageX` and `event.pageY`, or `event.x` and `event.y` in IE.

If you handle the event using jQuery, it'll fix things automatically, allowing you to simply use `pageX` and `pageY`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a library. The people who need to maintain the site after you will thank you.

[jQuery tooltip library](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a tool tip to me.  YUI provides a nice widget out of the box for this

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/tooltip.html